# How can I detect an EOF in assembly, nasm?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to detect an EOF character, or just any character at all, but it doesn't work, no error either.

```
section .data
    file db "text.txt", 0

section .bss
    char resb 1

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rax, 2
    mov rdi, file
    syscall
    mov rbx, rax

    mov rdi, rbx
    mov rax, 0
    mov rsi, char
    mov rdx, 1
    syscall

    mov rcx, char
    cmp rcx, -1
    je _endOfFile

    call _end

_endOfFile:
    print 1, file, 0
    ret

_end:
    mov rax, 3
    mov rdi, rbx
    syscall

    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

I expected it to print the name of the file, but it doesn't do anything. When I remove the cmp, and just make it jump it prints it fine. I also tried it for other characters and it didn't work for those either. I am really new to assembly, so I have no clue what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, a few layers of problems here.

Most fundamental is that there is no "EOF character".  Unlike ISO C's `getc()`, the Unix `read` system call doesn't signal end-of-file by reading back a particular character, it signals it by returning 0 as its return value.  So you need to check the value in `rax` after the read `syscall`.  If it is zero, then you have reached end-of-file.  If it is 1, then you successfully read a character into the memory location `char`.  If it is a smallish negative number, then an error occurred, and the negation of this value is an `errno` code.

The comparison code also has a few bugs.  First of all, `mov rcx, char` doesn't load the character from `char`, it loads the address of `char`, which naturally does not equal -1.  If you look, this is exactly similar to the `mov rsi, char` you used to set up the system call, which likewise put the address of `char` into rsi.

To specify the contents of memory at location `char`, you use square brackets: `mov rcx, [char]`.  However, that wouldn't be right either.  On x86-64, most instructions can operate
on 8, 16, 32 or 64 bit operands.  When at least one operand is a register, the size of the specified register dictates the operand size.  So `mov rcx, [char]` would load 8 bytes, of which the lowest would be the byte from `char`, and the other 7 would be whatever garbage happened to follow it in memory.

To load one byte, use an 8-bit register, like `cl`.  Then you need to likewise do the compare with only the 8-bit register, or else you're comparing against stuff that is not your character.

```
mov cl, [char]
cmp cl, -1
je got_ff
```

Though actually, in most cases, instead of `mov cl, [char]` it would be better to do `movzx ecx, byte [char]` which zeros out the upper bits of `rcx`.  `mov cl, [byte]` is defined as preserving those bits, which comes with a slight performance cost.

But actually actually, you don't need to load the character into a register at all; `cmp` works fine with a memory operand.

```
cmp byte [char], -1
je it_was_ff
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! So I use the code at the end to compare any chars, and I check rax to see if I have reached the end of the file? Also, do you mind explaining what the 'byte' does in cmp byte [char], -1?

Comment: @Josh: That's right.  The `byte` is for operand size again.  Just coding `cmp [char], -1` would be ambiguous, because neither the memory reference `[char]` nor the immediate `-1` specifies a size.  Should this instruction compare one byte, or two, four, eight?  So `byte` tells the assembler to emit the instruction that compares one byte.  If you wanted a 16-bit compare you would do `cmp word [my_integer], -1`, likewise `dword` and `qword` for 32 or 64 bits.

Comment: There **used to be** "EOF character" in Microsoft systems for backward compatibility with CP/M, namely `0x1A` alias `Ctrl-Z` , see [End-of-file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Note that `getc()` doesn't return an EOF *character* - it returns integer `-1` as in-band signalling that there was no character to read.  That makes it different from `(unsigned char)-1` zero-extended to an `int`, so you can still read any binary character, at least on a system where `CHAR_BIT` is less than the number of value bits in an `int`.  But yes, that's inherent in returning a character by value, instead of by reference with a separate return value like `scanf` or `fgets` or `fread`.